# Proxmox: Connect VMs in private networks

Tags: proxmox

I want to install VMs with private IPs in my Proxmox Cluster and route traffic between them.

Eg:

**VM1:**

```
192.168.1.10/24
```

**VM2:**

```
192.168.2.10/24
```

I'm not sure how this is done. Do I need VLANs? How can I route traffic between the two subnets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this, actually. Here's what I did:

1. Create two new Proxmox bridges, one for every subnet. You may add an address in each subnet to the Proxmox bridge, but it is not required.
2. Create a new VM for routing between the subnets. There are multiple solutions here, but what I chose was [pfSense](https://www.pfsense.org). This VM needs interfaces to both Proxmox bridges created in step 1. If you want to add further subnets, add all interfaces to this VM.
3. Enable routing in pfSense.
4. (optional) If you want to access these VMs from your host network, create static routes to these subnets with pfSense as the next hop in your routing device.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem by configuring the bridge to support **NAT**, which is basically creating a router.

```
vmbr0 (192.168.0.2/24, gw: 192.168.0.1) -> bridged to physical port
vmbr1 (10.0.0.1/24) -> local bridge for containers
```

If a container connected through the `vmbr1` bridge were to ping e.g. google.com, nothing would return. To tell vmbr1 to 'translate' traffic coming from this network to the vmbr2 network, I added the following lines to the `interfaces` file located in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet static
        address 10.0.0.1/24
        bridge-ports none
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0
-->        post-up   echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
-->        post-up   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '10.0.0.0/24' -o vmbr0 -j MASQUERADE
-->        post-down iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s '10.0.0.0/24' -o vmbr0 -j MASQUERADE
```

After saving changes, you can apply them without rebooting by using this command:

```
ifreload -a
```

#### Explanation:

The first line enables ipv4 forwarding.
The following two lines add/delete rules to/from the NAT table for forwarding traffic from the `10.0.0.0/24` subnet to the vmbr0 bridge. The `MASQUERADE` option replaces the source IP with that of the translating bridge (vmbr1).

Here's a more detailed [link](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Network_Configuration#sysadmin_network_masquerading).

iptables in general: https://www.karlrupp.net/en/computer/nat_tutorial